# python wget.download() throws OSError: Address family not supported by protocol

Tags: python, wget

I'm trying to download a model weights file from huggingface with python's wget library. What did I run:

```
import wget
wget.download("https://huggingface.co/h94/IP-Adapter/resolve/main/models/image_encoder/pytorch_model.bin")
```

what I've got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 1354, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1256, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1302, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1251, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1011, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 951, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1418, in connect
    super().connect()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 922, in connect
    self.sock = self._create_connection(
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 808, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 791, in create_connection
    sock = socket(af, socktype, proto)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 231, in __init__
    _socket.socket.__init__(self, family, type, proto, fileno)
OSError: [Errno 97] Address family not supported by protocol

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wget_to_oss.py", line 15, in <module>
    wget.download(args.url, out=args.save_dir)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wget.py", line 526, in download
    (tmpfile, headers) = ulib.urlretrieve(binurl, tmpfile, callback)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 247, in urlretrieve
    with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 525, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 542, in _open
    result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 502, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 1397, in https_open
    return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPSConnection, req,
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 1357, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 97] Address family not supported by protocol>
```

I totally have no idea what the error means (as well as how to handle) due to my lack of internet-protocol knowledge

Comment: btw, I cannot download the model via hf_hub_download() cuz it keeps giving me ConnectTimeoutError